# Resolving a promise inside a callback

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using a certain node.js library in which you define a callback function that needs to return a value.

Inside this callback I want to use a function from another library that returns a promise of that value.

How can I define the callback function to return the value from the resolved promise ?

How do I edit the following snippet so that I return the value to the callback only when then promise was resolved ?

```
Util_A.someFunction( (a)=>{
                Util_B.somePromise(a)
                    .then((result)=>{
                        // This is the value that I want to return to 
                        // the original function 'someFunction'
                        return result;
                    });

            }),
```

Comment: Hi, Try to return the Util_B.sommePropose(a)....stuff

Comment: *return the value to the callback* - this sentence doesn't make sense. This isn't how promises and callbacks work. Please, provide more meaningful example that shows what your case is.

Comment: What do you mean by "*define the callback function to return the value*"? Do you want to return it from the callback to the `Util_A`? What exactly is `Util_A.somecallback`? A more concrete example would make your question much easier to understand.

Comment: I think he wants to wait for the result of the promise, get the value and return it as the return value of the callback function passed to `Util_A.somecallback`, but that's not how it is supposed work...

Comment: You can't do either of those things. You can't return the value from the result of the promise to the callback, and you can't a value from the callback to an outer scope.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as unclear what you are asking, until you [edit] your question to tell us *where* exactly you want the `result` to be used

Comment: Sorry for my question to be unclear. I edited it a bit and hope it's clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if I understand correctly, `somecallback` would do something with the return value from the callback it calls.

Unless `somecallback` supports promises or other asynchronicity from the retval, there's no way to do this.

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted, this is the correct answer if @AKX understood the question correctly (which is, admittedly, unclear)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:?

```
new Promise(resolve => Util_A.somecallback(resolve))
    .then(a => Util_B.somePromise(a))
    .then(result => console.log(result))
    .catch (err => console.error(err.message));
```

**EDIT:** Better chaining of promises.

Comment: Instead of `Util_B.somePromise(data).then((result)=>{
                resolve(result);
            }).catch(e => reject(e));` you can just use `resolve(Util_B.somePromise(data))`

Comment: you an use `await` to hold the code while promises.

Comment: If this does what the OP wants, one should better write `new Promise(resolve => Util_A.somecallback(resolve)).then(a => Util_B.somePromise(a))`

Comment: @Bergi That's even more elegant! Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 0):

You should convert the `Util_A` function into a `Promise` based function. How ? Using the native [Util.promisify()](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/util.html) method of node.js *(I've made a custom implementation for the snippet)*.

**Never mix up callback/promise.**

```js
const Util_A = {
  somecallback: callback => callback(false, 'callback return'),
};

const Util_B = {
 somepromise: () => new Promise((resolve) => resolve('promise return')),
};

function promisify(func) {
  return () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    func((err, val) => {
      if (err) return reject(err);

      return resolve(val);
    });
  });
}

// Native Util.promisify() in node.js
promisify(Util_A.somecallback)()
 .then((ret) => {
   console.log(ret);
   
   return Util_B.somepromise();
 })
 .then((ret) => {
   console.log(ret);
 });
```